# Joomla update fails. Error 1267 Illegal mix of collations

Tags: joomla, updates, collation

I try to update some website that run in Joomla 3.4.8. and 3.5.0. Everytime I have tried to update them to 3.5.1 or to the latest 3.6.0. an error is displayed on Homepage like this:

`1267
Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'locate' SQL=SELECT m.id,m.id AS item_id,m.title,m.link,m.type,@tmp_search := '"menu-meta_description":"' AS tmp_search, @tmp_search_len := LENGTH(@tmp_search) AS tmp_search_len, @start := LOCATE(@tmp_search, m.params) AS tmp_start, @end := LOCATE('"', m.params, @start + @tmp_search_len) AS tmp_end, TRIM(SUBSTRING(m.params, @start + @tmp_search_len, @end - @start - @tmp_search_len)) AS metadescription,"" AS description,@tmp_search := '"page_title":"' AS tmp_search, @tmp_search_len := LENGTH(@tmp_search) AS tmp_search_len, @start := LOCATE(@tmp_search, m.params) AS tmp_start, @end := LOCATE('"', m.params, @start + @tmp_search_len) AS tmp_end, TRIM(SUBSTRING(m.params, @start + @tmp_search_len, @end - @start - @tmp_search_len)) AS metatitle,e.element as extension FROM #__menu AS m LEFT JOIN #__extensions AS e ON m.component_id = e.extension_id WHERE m.id = '101'`

Although in admin area seems to have the 3.6.0. version, the site crashes and the Homepage displays the error.

I have tried a lot of things the past two months like setting through phpMyAdmin all the collations to `"utf8_general_ci"` or `"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"` but none of these have fixed the problem.

I'd really appreciate if anybody could help me with this.

Thank you,

Apos

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the same issue, we ended up tracking it down to our extensions.  We had not upgraded them first before upgrading Joomla from 3.6 to 3.6.2.

Try to upgrade all your plugins first, then check the database at each step to make sure its ok.

Extension > Manage > Database

and hit the "Fix" button if there are any issues at every step. We had to upgrade in two steps, 3.5.4 to 3.6.0 and then to 3.6.2.  The database needed to be "fixed" during the first upgrade.  This happened on all our Joomla installs.

Hope that helps!